# Numix Theme Removal : Resulting Mixed Themes

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk

I tried installing *Numix* using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install numix-gtk-theme numix-icon-theme numix-wallpaper-saucy
```

But I didnt like it. So I tried removing it using

```
sudo apt-get remove numix-gtk-theme numix-icon-theme numix-wallpaper-saucy
```

Now I have a mixed theme of sorts. The drives are not showing up in the left dash panel.

The wifi icons are all discoulored.

Can someone suggest a way to restore all to the original 13.10 themes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh okay.. I figured it out myself. I installed Unity Tweak Tool and clicked on restore to default and it worked.